# I2Cデバイスをラズパイに複数接続時に正しいアドレスが認識されない

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

初質問失礼いたします。

現在秋月の[VL53L0X](https://akizukidenshi.com/catalog/g/gM-12590)をRaspberryPi 1台に対して2つ使用接続して使用したいと考えております。このToF距離センサーはI2Cアドレス"29"を持ち、ハードでの変更はできません。
ここで、2台をそれぞれ1台ずつ接続して、値の読み出しとXSHUT端子での電源オンオフの動作は確認できました。

しかし、2台並列に接続すると、XSHUTのオンオフに関わらず以下のようなありえないアドレスが認識されます。また、認識されるアドレスは試行するたびに変わります。

```
pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          03 04 -- 06 -- -- 09 -- 0b 0c -- 0e 0f 
10: 10 11 -- 13 14 15 -- 17 18 -- -- -- 1c 1d -- -- 
20: 20 -- -- 23 24 25 -- -- -- 29 2a 2b 2c -- -- 2f 
30: -- -- 32 33 -- 35 -- -- 38 39 3a -- -- 3d -- -- 
40: -- -- -- 43 44 45 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 4f 
50: -- -- -- -- -- 55 -- 57 58 -- 5a 5b -- 5d 5e -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 67 68 -- -- 6b -- 6d 6e -- 
70: 70 -- 72 73 74 75 76 77  

pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          03 04 -- 06 07 08 09 -- 0b -- -- -- -- 
10: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 -- 19 1a 1b -- -- -- 1f 
20: -- -- 22 -- 24 -- -- -- 28 29 2a 2b -- -- 2e -- 
30: 30 -- 32 33 -- -- -- -- 38 39 -- 3b 3c 3d 3e -- 
40: -- 41 42 43 -- 45 -- -- -- -- -- 4b 4c 4d 4e -- 
50: -- 51 52 53 -- 55 -- 57 58 59 5a -- 5c -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- 63 64 65 66 67 -- 69 -- 6b -- 6d -- 6f 
70: 70 -- 72 73 -- -- -- --
```

この状況の解決方法をご教授ください。

環境：
Raspberry Pi 4(4GB) OKdo版（RSコンポーネンツにて購入）

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi4 5.4.72-v7l+ #1 SMP Mon Oct 26 10:56:14 JST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: ある時期以後のOSカーネルを使って、別々のバスに接続する必要があるようです。[Raspberry Pi OS ① I2Cバスがたくさん使える](https://www.denshi.club/pc/raspi/raspberry-pi-os-1-i2c.html), [Raspberry PI Multiple I2C Devices](https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-PI-Multiple-I2c-Devices/) それ以前でも工夫すれば出来そうですが。[メモ：i2c-gpioドライバでRaspberry PiにI2Cポートを追加](https://qiita.com/spicemanjp/items/50474e56ddccabf02b01)

Comment: すみません、これに近い実装方法は困難だということでしょうか
https://team432.jpn.org/?p=380

Comment: 実績があるなら出来るのでは？ ただし、装置の購入先(は良いとして)/結線の改造方法や使用するソフトウエア(OS/Python/スクリプト)の種類や版数とか作業手順など細かいところまで参照記事と同一に出来ているかどうかでしょうね。あるいは、自明のこととして参照記事には書かれなかった作業があるのかもしれないし、結線とか工作精度の問題で電流電圧の過不足とかノイズの増加/周波数の変動なんかが発生しているのかもしれません。そういう方向では無く複数のI2Cバスを有効にして、別々のバスに装置を接続することでアドレス変更無しに同じ装置を複数使えるようにするのがコメントで紹介した記事だと思います。

Comment: 「ハードでの変更はできません」と書かれていますが、ソフトウェアでI2Cアドレスを書き換える方法が書かれたページのURLをご存じなのですから、一方のセンサーのアドレスを29以外に書き換えて、両方のセンサーをI2Cポートに接続するのが素直だと思います。
同じアドレスのICが複数I2Cに接続されていると、信号が重なって波形が乱れますから、I2Cアドレスの認識結果が異常になったのだと思われます。

Comment: 仰るとおりで、一旦片方のセンサーを外した状態でI2Cアドレスを変更して2つ並列で認識させることはできました。また、その際にXSHUTをアクティブLowにするとI2Cdetectで認識されなくなることも確認しました。
一方でこの方法でのアドレス変更はラズパイの電源を切ってI2Cへの給電をやめると初期化されてしまうようで、今回の用途の関係上毎回物理配線から触らないと起動しないといけないのは不都合なので困っています
このあたりの記述不足で、また2日遅れの返信で申し訳ないです

Answer (score 1):

１）片方のセンサー（"センサーA"と呼びます）の電源を切っておいて、もう一方のセンサー("センサーB"と呼びます)のI２Cアドレスを変更する。
２）センサーAに電源を入れて、センサーAのI2Cアドレスを変更する
という操作をラズパイの電源を切らないで行うには、センサーAの電源をラズパイでOn/Offできるように細工する必要があります。

例えば、[ＮＪＭ２８６５](https://akizukidenshi.com/catalog/c/creg33v)、のような制御端子を持つ電源レギュレータIC を使って、GPIOの信号(GPIO-XX)でAE-VL53LOX（センサーＡ）の電源のON/OFFができるようにする（下図(I2Cの信号は省略してます)）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そうすれば、ラズパイで

1. GPIO-XX(OUTPUT, プルアップ)をLowにする。(センサーAの電源が切れる）
2. センサーＢのI2Cアドレスを29以外に変更する。(XSHUTに接続されているGPIO-YYを利用)
3. GPIO-YYをHighにする(センサーAに電源が入る）

これで２つのセンサーに異なるI2Cアドレスが設定されるので、ラズパイから自由に両方のセンサーを制御できるようになる。

電源レギュレータは、制御端子があって、出力電圧が3.3Vの低損失型(5Vの入力で3.3Vの出力ができる）ものなら何でも良いです。
たまたま部品箱に入っていたので、例にしましたが表面実装のICは扱いにくいのでリードが出ているものをお勧めします。

Comment: 「3.GPIO-YYをHighにする(センサーAに電源が入る）」は「3.GPIO-XXをHighにする(センサーAに電源が入る）」に訂正します。

Answer (score 1):

I2Cなら、SCLを有効とするデバイスのみに供給するようにゲートしてやればいいです